# Are continuous paths in the product measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $S$ be a metric space equipped with some $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{B}$ (borelians?) and $T:=\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$. Consider the space $S^T=\{$maps from $T$ to $S\}$ and equip $S^T$ with the product measure $\mathcal{B}^{\otimes T}=\sigma\{\pi_t : t\in T\}$, i.e. the smallest sigma field generated by the projections $\pi_t : S^T\to S$, $\omega\mapsto \omega(t)$ . Now I was wondering if the set of continuous functions $C(T,S):=\{\omega\in S^T : \omega$ is continuous$\}$ is in the product $\sigma-algebra$ $\mathcal{B}^{\otimes T}$ and how to prove it. I think the first question would be to know for a fixed $t$, if $C_t$ the set of continuous function in $t$ are in $\mathcal{B}^{\otimes T}$. Even if they are Then $C(T,S)=\bigcap\limits_{t\in T} C_t$ and since this intersection is uncountable, I could not conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Given a subset $A\subseteq T$ and a subset $C\subseteq S^T$, say that $C$ depends only on $A$ if for all $f,g\in S^T$, if $f|_A=g|_A$ then $f\in C$ iff $g\in C$.  Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of subsets of $S^T$ that depend only on some countable set.  It is easy to see that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (when taking a union or intersection of sets, just take the union of the sets they depend on).  Also, $\mathcal{A}$ contains the $\sigma$-algebra generated by each projection $\pi_t$, since any preimage under $\pi_t$ depends only on $\{t\}$.  So, $\mathcal{A}$ contains $\mathcal{B}^{\otimes T}$.  However, $C(T,S)\not\in\mathcal{A}$ (assuming $S$ has more than one point), since whether a function is continuous does not depend on its values only on some fixed countable set.

Comment: Thank you.This was tricky. I am still curious about the set of functions continuous in just a fixed point $t$. Are they $\mathcal{B}^{\otimes T}$ measurable?

Comment: The same reasoning applies to them.